# How to replace character in string upon a condition - python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I want to replace `'` with space if it comes before `s` or after `I`, this is my code but the output isn't changing?

`s` type is `<class 'str'>`

```
for w in s:
   if(w[-2:] == "'s") or (w[2:] == "I'"):
       s = s[w].replace("'",'   ')
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
From your partial description, it seems that you're iterating through a simple string, but expecting a single character to somehow equal a string of length two.  This is not possible.  We need complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w` is just a single character, so `w[-2:]` will not include the characters before `w` in `s`. You could have looped over indexes in `s` and used `s[index-1:index+1]` to match a substring.

But you don't need a loop, you can just use `replace()` to replace each substring.

```
s = s.replace("'s", " s").replace("I'", "I ")
```